# how to refresh bootstrap modal (div) without refresh whole page in asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I want to refresh bootstrap model div without refresh whole page in asp.net 
I already tried with update panel  but its not working with bootstrap model

on button click a bootstrap model appear and i want to refresh only model div not whole page

anyone have idea?

Comment: you can rewrite innerHTML of the DOM Component by javascript

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers any reference please?

Comment: @KKZone: A quick Google search finds the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML  As well as tons of examples.  How are you refreshing the whole page?  Why not just update that specific content with JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean about "I  already tried with update panel but its not working with bootstrap model"? Kindly show us your existing code so we can isolate the problem.